# Win8/VB6 can't find project or library for common functions (str, Space$)

Tags: windows-8, vb6

I have installed VB6 on my Windows 8 64bit laptop, I installed SP6 and when I try to run projects that I had working on my windows 7 32bit laptop I am running into a problem with common functions like Space$ or Str, where it tells me "Can't find project or library".

After some googling I have tried copying over my comdlg32.dll from the windows 7 laptop over to the syswow64 folder on the win8 laptop but saw no change. I have installed SP4 after I read that would solve it but that didn't work either. I also read that msderun.dll would help but after dropping that in syswow64 I did not see any change either.

Does anyone know how to fix this on Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Find msvbrun60.dll (in 32 bit windows type `regsvr32 msvbvm60.dll`, for 64 bit do the same with `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 msvbrun60.dll`). All those functions are in vba library which is msvbvm60.dll. If that fails reinstall the runtime files http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887.

Comment: I wasn't able to find msvbrun60.dll, I could find msvbvm60.dll though and registered that. It was already referenced in my project however under "Visual Basic for Applications". I also followed that link and tried installing it on my Win8 machine but it didn't seem to do anything. I then installed it on a win7-64 VMWare machine and didn't see a msvbrun60.dll either, just msvbvm60.dll. Where can I go from here?

Comment: The methods you mentioned, Space$() and Str(), are part of the "Visual Basic for Applications" (VBA) library provided through "msvbvm60.dll". It could be that an object/property other than Space$() and Str() is pointed at when it tells you a library is missing. Open the References dialog ("Project" menu > "References") and missing references will be prefixed by a big "MISSING: ".